# Как при нажатии на кнопку одного виджета выполнить код в другом виждете?

Tags: c++, qt

Создал класс наследующий от `QWidget`: окно с одной кнопкой. 
Хочу создать другой класс который тоже наследует от `QWidget` и имеет 2 кнопки.

Нужно чтобы при нажатии кнопки первого класса я мог переключиться на другой класс, но в одном окне.

Comment: Да, объяснять я не умею. Но попробую.
Я создал класс, назовем его Класс1. Он наследует от QWidget и то что он делает: показывает окно с одной кнопкой. Я создал Класс2 наследующий тоже от QWidget который в свою очередь показывает две кнопки. То что мне нужно, это перейти ко второму Виджету Класса2 нажав на кнопку Класса1 оставаясь в том же окне.

Comment: http://gifmaker.cc/PlayGIFAnimation.php?folder=2016032500x4mAQWOUqWBTXqc8oqSHU0&file=output_niJVEg.gif

Comment: Вот так.........

Comment: @AstemirTsechoev у меня по вашей ссылке открывается ходящий на задних лапах котик. Вставьте поясняющую картинку прямо в вопрос.

Comment: Мне уже объяснили, спасибо. Я начал использовать QStackedWidget

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пример создания окна с переключением между двумя виджетами внутри одного окна.

В первом виджете кнопка переключает на второй виджет. На втором виджете одна кнопка показывает сообщение, а другая переключает обратно на первый виджет. Не забудьте разнести по `h` и `cpp` файлам эти классы:

```
#include <QWidget>
#include <QVBoxLayout>

class Widget1: public QWidget {
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Widget1() {
        pb_next.setText("Next");
        connect(&pb_next, SIGNAL(clicked()), SIGNAL(next()));

        QVBoxLayout* layout = new QVBoxLayout();
        layout->addWidget(&pb_next);

        setLayout(layout);
    }

private:
    QPushButton pb_next;

signals:
    void next();
};
```

```
class Widget2: public QWidget {
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Widget2() {
        pb_click.setText("Click me!");
        connect(&pb_click, SIGNAL(clicked()), SIGNAL(my_clicked()));

        pb_back.setText("Back!");
        connect(&pb_back, SIGNAL(clicked()), SIGNAL(back()));

        QVBoxLayout* layout = new QVBoxLayout();
        layout->addWidget(&pb_click);
        layout->addWidget(&pb_back);

        setLayout(layout);
    }

private:
    QPushButton pb_click;
    QPushButton pb_back;

signals:
    void my_clicked();
    void back();
};
```

```
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QStackedWidget>
#include <QMessageBox>


class MyMainWindow: public QMainWindow {
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MyMainWindow() {
        setCentralWidget(&stackedWidget);

        stackedWidget.addWidget(&w1);
        stackedWidget.addWidget(&w2);

        connect(&w1, SIGNAL(next()), SLOT(next()));
        connect(&w2, SIGNAL(back()), SLOT(back()));
        connect(&w2, SIGNAL(my_clicked()), SLOT(about()));
    }

public slots:
    void next() {
        stackedWidget.setCurrentWidget(&w2);
    }

    void back() {
        stackedWidget.setCurrentWidget(&w1);
    }

    void about() {
        QMessageBox::information(this, QString(), "!!!");
    }

private:
    QStackedWidget stackedWidget;
    Widget1 w1;
    Widget2 w2;
};
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо!